# Connection strings for local sql server with integrated auth

Tags: sql-server, connection

I am trying to connect from my nodejs and sequelize based web app, to a local SQL Server (2016) instance. I want to use Windows Integrated Authentication. I currently have this

```
  const sequelize = new Sequelize('Demo-DB', null, null, {
    dialect: 'mssql',
    dialectModulePath: 'sequelize-msnodesqlv8',
    logging: false,
    dialectOptions: {
      driver: 'SQL Server Native Client 11.0',
      instanceName: 'MSSQLSERVER01',
      trustedConnection: true,
    });
```

Note for those unfamiliar with sequelize, the two `null` params are username and password. This all works, however, I am hoping to use a connection string in the format:

> mssql://root:password@localhost:1433/Demo-DB

? I have only come across connection strings in the format:

> Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Demo-DB;Trusted_Connection=yes;

Is this possible and if so how to specify integrated auth?

Comment: Have you read the sequelize documentation? https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-msnodesqlv8

Comment: @DanGuzman Yes, none of the given examples just use a connection string

Comment: The JSON described in the documentation is the connection string. You can't just take a connection string used by one API and expect it to work in a different one. JSON format is the defacto standard in the javascript world.